# Row/column permutation

Tags: c, arrays

I have a quadratic matrix(two-dimensional dynamic array of pointers) and need to change rows/columns order. The matrix is very big that's why I have decided just to change pointers instead of copying all of elements. I also have another array which specifies a computation.
 Rows permutation specifies this way:
4,3,2,1 - it means that the first row must be on the fourth place, the second row must be on the third place, etc.
The same situation is with the columns.
[image: http://xmages.net/storage/10/1/0/8/6/thumb/thumb_40561a35.jpg]

How to implement such algorithm of changing of rows order(permutation of of pointers)? Here it is my version, but it doesn't work. I want to copy pointers but element is copied instead of it and then appears a segmentation fault. 
When I add '&' to get address, the compiler says that it is a syntax error:

```
orderOfRows[i] = &auxMatrix[computation[i]];
```

Here it is my code:

```
static int N = 6;
static int **orderOfRows;
int **sourceMatrix;
int **auxMatrix;

int main() {
int* computation = (int*)malloc(N*sizeof(int));

computation[0] = 1;
computation[1] = 6;
computation[2] = 3;
computation[3] = 7;
computation[4] = 4;
computation[5] = 2;

}
printf("After computation has been done: \n");
changeRowOrder(computation);

 void changeRowOrder(int *computation) {
int i;
// change rows order and dopy them into a temp array
for(i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    // static arrays
    orderOfRows[i] = auxMatrix[computation[i]];
}
// recover matrix
for(i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    auxMatrix[i] = orderOfRows[i];
}


void allocate2dMemory() {

int i = 0;
sourceMatrix = (int**)malloc(N * sizeof(int *));

if(sourceMatrix == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
    exit(2);
}

for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    sourceMatrix[i] = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    if(sourceMatrix[i] == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        exit(2);
    }
}

auxMatrix = (int**)malloc(N * sizeof(int *));

if(auxMatrix == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
    exit(2);
}

for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    auxMatrix[i] = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    if(auxMatrix[i] == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        exit(2);
    }
}

 orderOfRows = (int**)malloc(N * sizeof(int *));

if(orderOfRows == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
    exit(2);
}

for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    orderOfRows[i] = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    if(orderOfRows[i] == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        exit(2);
    }
}

}
}
```

I will spend 2*N(copy pointers and then recover) operations instead of N*N.
And I have another question: how I can do the permutation of columns using this idea? If it isn't possible how can I do the permutation of columns but not to copy all elements of the matrix? The programming language is only C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
orderOfRows[i] = &auxMatrix[computation[i]];
```

you should have

```
for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
{
    orderOfRows[i][j] = auxMatrix[computation[i]][j];
}
```

---

And one more thing:

if you have`computation[1] = 6`, it means that by doing `auxMatrix[computation[i]]` you try to access `auxMatrix[6]`, which you can't do because `auxMatrix`'s size is 6x6.

Comment: Thanks for idea, but the line shoud be for(i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        orderOfRows[computation[i]] = auxMatrix[i];
    }

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to swap both rows and columns without copying, you are going to need to have two auxiliary indices:

```
int *row_index;
int *col_index;
```

and access the elements of your matrix using these:

```
element = matrix[row_index[row]][col_index[col]];
```

To swap a row or column, you simply swap the corresponding elements of row_index or col_index.

Comment: please,can you give an example, how can I change the order of columns. I understand how can I change the order of rows, I have described it above (see the picture). I can't imagine the operation of changing columns order, because we haven't pointer with the beginning of every column.